# Help in Python Addon Development

Tags: python, kodi

I'm working on a simple slideshow addon for kodi,

```
import xbmcaddon

import xbmcgui

import time


xbmc.executebuiltin('ShowPicture("special://home/addons/script.cosmos.slide/fanart.jpg")')

time.sleep(2)

xbmc.executebuiltin('ShowPicture("special://home/addons/script.cosmos.slide/fanart2.jpg")')
```

I'm searching for stopping the player and close it. Is there any solution?

Comment: maybe this can help ..... google `xbmc.executebuiltin`  to get this   https://kodi.wiki/view/List_of_built-in_functions

Comment: This does not belong to Raspberry Pi. It is a programming question. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.